# Actualizar textura Kivy con evento

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

Me gustaría utilizar Kivy para mostrar imágenes adquiridas desde una cámara industrial. Para ello, he partido del siguiente ejemplo que utiliza un método de adquisición mediante OpenCV.

```
# coding:utf-8
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

A partir de este ejemplo, he sustituido la adquisición de OpenCV por una clase propia que adquiere imágenes de la cámara en uso. El problema que tengo es que dependiendo de la configuración de la cámara, la velocidad de adquisición puede ser variable y si esta es más baja que los fps-s que se han configurado para la actualización de la imagen de kivy, la aplicación se ralentiza mucho porque se queda a la espera de recibir la imagen y consume muchos recursos.

Lo que me gustaría es poder actualizar la textura de la imagen a partir de un evento, en vez de con un periodo cíclico (Clock.schedule_interval). Es decir, tener un hilo de ejecución que esté continuamente esperando imágenes de la cámara y que cuando estas lleguen, se actualice la textura con un evento.

Algo me dice que esto es algo que se puede lograr con el event dispatche de kivy, pero no se bien cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear crear una funcion que se ejecute de manera asíncrona a la aplicación de kivy. Para hacer esto necsitas importar primero  `asyncio` y tambien el modulo de kivy: `async_runTouchApp`. Ya con esto tienes todas las funciones que necesitas.

```
import asyncio

from kivy.app import async_runTouchApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

#Esto solo es el diseño de widgets
kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Press me'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: label
            text: 'Button is "{}"'.format(btn.state)
'''

#Este metodo ejecuta la aplicacion de kivy como una subrutina
async def run_app_happily(root, other_task):
    #configuramos la ejecucion de la aplicacion desde asyncio
    await async_runTouchApp(root, async_lib='asyncio')  # Se ejecuta kivy
    print('App done')
    # Cancelamos otras tareas que puedan estar corriendo
    other_task.cancel()

#Este metodo es tambien ejecutado como subrutina. es un ciclo que periodicamente ejecuta algo
async def waste_time_freely():
    try:
        while True:
            print('Sitting on the beach')
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        print('Wasting time was canceled', e)
    finally:
        # Imprime cuando se cancela la aplicación
        print('Done wasting time')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Esto corre ambos metodos
    def root_func():
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)  # root widget
        other_task = asyncio.ensure_future(waste_time_freely())
        return asyncio.gather(run_app_happily(root, other_task), other_task)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(root_func())
    loop.close()
```

En vez de imprimir algo puedes esperar por la llegada de una nueva imagen, y cuando la recibas mandarla a kivy